# Could you elaborate how to use the pattern adjective + to infinitive?

Tags: meaning

I am still confused in using the pattern `adjective + to infinitive`.

The 2 sentences below are given for examples.

- I am lazy to study.
- It is lazy for me to study.

Could you elaborate how to use the pattern ?

Comment: As @Barrie's answer indicates, neither sentence is valid. So I think asking which is correct is just "too localised"

Comment: But the presenting question is valid -- there are several different kinds of "Adjective + _to_ + Infinitive", and they're complex.

Comment: For example, "he was crazy to think he could get away with it" is correct.

Comment: Exactly the kind of thing I meant.

Comment: You need to provide better examples. The question is clearer without them right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you may have confused two types of *lazy* constructions.

As a predicate adjective with a human subject, *lazy* does not take an **object** complement, infinitive or other. So neither of the sentences you give is a "pattern" (or ***Construction***, as it's technically called). The following sentences -- examples of the [four different types of English complement clause](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/complmnt.html) -- are therefore **all** ungrammatical, as indicated by the asterisk.

- **He is lazy to do that.*  (Infinitive complement - untensed)
- **He is lazy doing that.*  (Gerund complement - untensed)
- **He is lazy that he does that.* (*That* complement - tensed)
- **He is lazy what he does.* (Embedded question complement - tensed)

However, as a predicate adjective with a subject denoting a volitional action, instead of a human actor, *lazy* (or *just lazy* -- *just* seems a likely addition) **may** take either untensed type of **subject** complement, though tensed complements seem ungrammatical with it.

- *(For him) to do that would be just lazy (of him).*
- *(His) doing that is just lazy (of him).*
- **That he does that is just lazy (of him).*
- **What he does is just lazy (of him).*

And with an infinitive subject complement, [***Extraposition***](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/extrapos.html) is usually applied:

- *It would be lazy (of him) (for him) to do that.*

though Extraposition of gerund subject complements is not:

- **It is lazy (of him) doing that.*

By the way, there are plenty of adjectives that work differently from *lazy*. So this is not about any general pattern "Adjective + *to* + Infinitive". Rather, this is about the predicate adjective *lazy* and its usage. Which predicate adjective you use determines what kinds of constructions you can use with it; and every adjective is **different**. Welcome to English syntax.

Answer (score 7):

A native speaker would say neither.  The only possibility is *I am too lazy to study.*

Answer (score 3):

Neither of those questions make much sense; the first is poorly constructed and makes little sense, while the second actually means something, which is that *if I study, I am lazy.* However, that is illogical and not very sensible. So, there is a difference between the two; the first means almost nothing (the only interpretation would be that *since I am lazy, I do not study*), and the second means that studying is lazy.